# Convert spreads to prices for bonds via duration

Tags: fixed-income, duration

I have the price of a bond and would like to convert it to spreads. Is this possible by just having dollar duration?

Secondly, if I just care about the relative spreads of multiple bonds, is it enough to consider their prices and dollar durations? Would I simply divide the price by the dollar duration to get relative spreads?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misread your question, **NO**: Spread calculation (calibration) is a **root-finding** exercise. In the simplest case (flat rate curves), given market price $P$ and reference yield $r$ (e.g. treasury rate), which spread level $s$ ensures that

$$
s:PV(r,s,t,T)\equiv\sum_{i}c_ie^{-(r+s)(T-t_i)}\stackrel{!}{=}P
$$

In root-finding, we can employ **Newton's method** and iterate towards the correct spread level $s$ given some initial guess $s_0$

$$
s_{n+1}=s_n-\frac{PV(r,s_n,t,T)-P}{\left.\frac{\partial PV(r,s,t,T)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=s_n}}=s_n+\frac{PV(r,s_n,t,T)-P}{\mathrm{Dollar\ Duration(DV01)}}
$$

The last equality is true as:

$$
dPV/dy = dPV/dr = dPV/ds = -\sum_{i}(T-t_i)c_ie^{-(r+s)(T-t_i)}
$$

i.e. $\mathrm{DV01=CS01}$. Yet, given only the bond price and its duration is not sufficient - We also need the reference rate level, $r$. But if we know $r$, we have $s=y-r$ and we do not need the value or the duration in the first place.

HTH?

Comment: What if I don’t care about the absolute level of spread; but just want to compare a relative level of spreads? Would it be enough to have prices and dollar duration?

Comment: Assuming equal times-to-maturity and coupons across bonds then, yes, price levels are sufficient to rank spreads: Lowest price = largest spread. I'd say the case with different maturities and coupons require some more analysis.

Comment: Would the duration be enough to compensate for time to maturity as it’s a proxy for that?

Comment: Hi, at this point I'd say: Please update your initial post so that it better reflects your ideas and questions, ok?

Comment: Added second part to the question